# Blog loop in Shopify not working

Tags: loops, blogs, shopify

I have the following block of code in my index.liquid

```
<div class="news-notable">
            <h2>New &amp; Notable</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for article in blogs[blog.news].articles limit: 4 %}
                <li><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a><br />
                <span class="date">{{ article.published_at | date: '%b %d, %Y' }}</span></li>
                {% endfor %}
             </ul>
        </div>
```

Nothing is being outputted after the h2. I've also tried just using

```
{% for article in blogs.articles %}
```

And that didn't work either.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the blog **handle** inside the square brackets.

For instance, if your blog handle is `news`, your for loop would be:

```
{% for article in blogs[news].articles limit: 4 %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

or:

```
{% for article in blogs.news.articles limit: 4 %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: aahhhhh okay makes sense. I'll try this when I get home. Thank you!